# Can I limit a service account's authorization to specific images within GCP container registery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I'd like to have multiple environments setup of my application, and each environment should only have access to push/pull images from a specific image like `eu.gcr.io/project-name/abcxyz`.

Is this possible? It seems I can only grant a "global" role of `Storage Object Creator`- but then this gives the service account access to all the images within the project?

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly achieve this. But, thanks to the [Artifact registry (new product in Beta )](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/quickstart), you have a workaround to achieve this.

- Create a new repository of type `Docker`
- Publish your images (and versions of each image) on this repo
- Grant the service account that you want on the **repo**. -> You don't yet have image level authorization, but, as you can create several repos in the same zone, there is no problem for limiting the right like this.